# mockK cannot differentiate types in every statements

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I am writing a method in Kotlin which returns elasticsearch indices that have an alias assigned to them:

```kotlin
    fun getActiveIndices(cluster: ElasticsearchCluster): List<IndexModel> {
        val aliases = elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(GetAllAliasesCommand(cluster))
        val indices = elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(GetAllIndicesCommand(cluster))
        indices.forEach{ it.active = aliases.any { alias -> it.name == alias.index } }
        return indices.filter { !it.irregular && it.active }
    }
```

Where `GetAllAliasesCommand` and `GetAllIndicesCommand` are subclasses of `ElasticsearchCommand<T>`.
I am trying to test this method's behavior using mockK:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `getActiveIndices should make correct calls`() {
        val aliases = listOf(.. A list of AliasModel)
        val indices = listOf(.. A list of IndexModel)

        every { elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(any<GetAllAliasesCommand>()) } returns aliases
        every { elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(any<GetAllIndicesCommand>()) } returns indices

        val result = indexService.getActiveIndices(ElasticsearchCluster.SOME_CLUSTER)

        verify { elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(any<GetAllAliasesCommand>()) }
        verify { elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(any<GetAllIndicesCommand>()) }

        assert(result == listOf(.. A list of IndexModel))
    }
```

The problem is that mockK cannot differentiate between `any<GetAllIndicesCommand>()` and `any<GetAllAliasesCommand>()` in `every` statement so both `elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(any<GetAllIndicesCommand>())` and 
`elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(any<GetAllAliasesCommand>())` returns `indices`. Which means it applies the last `every` statement. Is there a way to make it return based on command type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to use [ofType](https://mockk.io/#matchers) matcher for this purpose. So the final code is:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `getActiveIndices should make correct calls`() {
        val aliases = listOf(.. A list of AliasModel)
        val indices = listOf(.. A list of IndexModel)

        every { elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(ofType(GetAllAliasesCommand::class)) } returns aliases
        every { elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(ofType(GetAllIndicesCommand::class)) } returns indices

        val result = indexService.getActiveIndices(ElasticsearchCluster.SOME_CLUSTER)

        verify { elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(ofType(GetAllIndicesCommand::class)) }
        verify { elasticsearchCommandExecutor.execute(ofType(GetAllAliasesCommand::class)) }

        assert(result == listOf(.. A list of IndexModel))
    }
```